# why can't my javascript detect for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm using [`mdetect.js`](http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/JavaScript/mdetect.js) as obtained from mobileesp.com. The file looks perfect for what I need, and I've saved it locally. Then on my HTML page, I want to call one of the functions and if it returns true (i.e. user is on mobile device) display a table at the top of the page saying our site doesn't support mobile devices currently. However, before even getting there I've already failed:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mdetect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(DetectIphoneOrIpod());
</script>
<p>this is normal body text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I haven't even gotten to the complicated stuff (for me at least). Why won't it write true or false depending on what's returned from that function? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I know this seems Obvious, but check that your function name is right. JavaScript usually is camelcased, with the first word lowercase.

Comment: I swear I've triple-checked; see: [mdetect script](http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/JavaScript/mdetect.js)

Comment: try to remove document.write and call that function alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mdetect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (DetectIphoneOrIpod()) {
        document.write("<table>...</table>");
    }
</script>
<p>this is normal body text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, you probably want to use the `DetectSmartphone()` or `DetectMobileQuick()` functions to detect more mobile devices than just iPhones and iPod Touches.

Comment: How would I make that check for "false" so I can test via desktop browser? (Sorry, this is my first JS project.) I still can't even just get document.write(function()); to do anything.

Comment: if (!DetectIphoneOrIpod()) should let you test on the desktop.  Note the addition of the exclamation mark!

Comment: Color me silly... all that and it turns out I had a slightly fubar'd version of mdetect.js. When I re-downloaded, everything was fine. Thanks for your patience! Your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem there is, but if you're using that entire file just for that function, it's overkill. Here's a trimmed down version which should also be easier to debug:

```
function isSmallIDevice() {
    return navigator.userAgent.search(/iPhone|iPod/i) > -1;
}
```

Comment: The iPhone and iPod Touch are not the only mobile devices in existence!

Comment: @mttrb: I know. I was slimming the function down directly from the file.

Comment: Yeah, I now see the OP was only using the DetectIPhoneOrIpod function.